# Is a convex function defined on a convex open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $K$ be a convex open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f$ a convex function defined on $K$; how to show that $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Can you prove it for $n = 1$? See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24676/convex-function-in-open-interval-is-continuous) for that case.

Comment: @t.b. can you say more about why n=1 generalizes to the present case?  The link in the only answer here is broken.  It seems like all you get is cross-sectional Lipschitz and continuity properties.

Comment: I should mention that I heaved a sigh of relief when I thought that "cross-sectional Lipschitz" would be enough, but the thing is it's not just one lipschitz constant, or even one for each of the n axial directions.  It's a different constant for every cross section.

Comment: @Jeff: See e.g. Theorem 3.3.1 in [these notes](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_3.pdf)